# MySQL not returning to my needs

Tags: php, mysql, function, select

I am trying to create a function that is going to check if an user exists based on their email. After comparing the submitted email with the email entries in my database, I want to see if an user is legit or not. This is what I have coded so far:

```
function user_exists($email)
{
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `imgit_users` WHERE `email`='$email'");

    return (mysql_result($query, 0) <= 1) ? true : false;
}
```

And I used it like this:

```
if (user_exists($register_email) === true)
{
    echo 'Fail';
    $errors[] = 'The supplied email is already in use';
}   
else 
{
    if (empty($errors))
    {
        $user_id = user_register($register_username, $register_email, $register_password);
        $_SESSION['imgit_uid'] = $user_id;
        echo 'Okay';
    }
}
```

My script keeps returning Okay instead of Fail, even if I type in the same email everytime. Ideas?

Comment: Show us your INSERT, ie your user_register() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return (mysql_result($query, 0) >= 1) ? true : false;
```

Swap the <= to >=

Answer (score 2):

```
return (mysql_result($query, 0) <= 1) ? true : false;
```

So you want to return true if the result is less than or equal to 1. So if it's 1 or 0? Perhaps there is your error, to check if it is less than 1 and swap the true / false. Or check if it is equal to 1.

Comment: I have tried with `return (mysql_result($query, 0) == 1) ? true : false;` but it's the same problem.

Comment: What if there is more than one user with the email in database ? the user doesn't exist?

Comment: I want to prevent that. I want to prevent users from registering using the same email address - I want the emails to stay unique.

Comment: Wanting to is cool :) but you're not doing it here. You have to set a unique constraint in database or check in your code every time on the insert or update

Comment: I didn't think that I'll stumble across this IRL that fast: http://geekandpoke.typepad.com/geekandpoke/2011/07/good-coders.html :)

Answer (score 1):

```
return (mysql_result($query, 0) >= 1) ? true : false;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer not use `COUNT()` to check if an email is already used, instead I'd use something like

```
function user_exists($email)
{
 $sql = sprintf( 
  'SELECT 1 FROM imgit_users WHERE email = \'%s\' LIMIT 0,1', 
  mysql_real_escape_string( $email ) 
 );
 $result = mysql_query( $sql );
 // add error handling
 return 1 === mysql_num_rows( $result );
}
```